# How does one get Flask-Migrate to read the current app config?

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I am having trouble running `flask db migrate`.  I have run `flask db init` without issue and have modified the resulting `migrations/env.py` file to focus only on a specific schema in an existing MS SQL Server database.  It is acting like the `migrations/env.py: run_migrations_online()` method is not finding the correct app configuration.  It wants to create a default sqlite in memory db instead.

I am defining `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` in `create_app()` where that reads in a local config file:

```
app.config.from_object('app.local_settings')
```

The config for the mssql db should be:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = \
    "mssql+pyodbc://db-dev.my.company.com/devdb?driver=SQL+Server"
```

My app entry point looks like:

```
from app import create_app

try:
    app = create_app()
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
    raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app.run(debug=True)
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(repr(e))
        print(repr(e))
```

The definition of `create_app()` is in the `__init__.py` of the app module:

```
import pyodbc
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, auth_required, \
    hash_password
from flask_security.models import fsqla_v2 as fsqla

# Instantiate Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Instantiate Flask extensions
csrf_protect = CSRFProtect(app=app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app=app)
mail = Mail(app=app)
migrate = Migrate(app=app, db=db)


# Initialize Flask Application
def create_app(extra_config_settings={}):
    # Load common settings
    app.config.from_object('app.settings')
    # Load environment specific settings
    app.config.from_object('app.local_settings')
    # Load extra settings from extra_config_settings param
    app.config.update(extra_config_settings)

    # print(pyodbc.drivers())

    # Setup Flask-SQLAlchemy
    db.init_app(app)

    # Setup Flask-Migrate
    migrate.init_app(app=app, db=db)

    # Setup Flask-Mail
    mail.init_app(app)

    # Setup WTForms CSRFProtect
    csrf_protect.init_app(app)

    # Register blueprints
    from .views import register_blueprints
    register_blueprints(app)

    # Setup an error-logger to send emails to app.config.ADMINS
    init_email_error_handler(app)

    # Setup Flask-User to handle user account related forms
    from .models.user import User, UserRegisterForm, UserProfileForm, \
        UserLoginForm
    from .views.main import user_profile_page
    from .models.roles import Role

    # APIs
    from .views import register_api, SchoolAPI
    register_api(app, SchoolAPI, 'school_api', '/school/', pk='school_id')

    # @app.context_processor
    # def context_processor():
    #   return dict(user_manager=user_manager)

    fsqla.FsModels.set_db_info(db)

    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)

    return app
```

I have modified the `migrations/env.py` file as:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

from flask import current_app

from alembic import context

config = context.config

fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

config.set_main_option(
    'sqlalchemy.url',
    str(current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.get_engine().url).replace(
        '%', '%%'))
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata


def include_name(name, type_, parent_names):
    result = False
    if type_ == "schema":
        return name in ["MySchema"]
    else:
        return True


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    print(f'run_migrations_offline: {url}')
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        version_table_schema='MySchema',
        include_schemas=True,
        include_name=include_name
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    connectable = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.get_engine()

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            version_table_schema='MySchema',
            include_schemas=True,
            include_name=include_name,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

When I run `flask db migrate` I get:

```
H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds signi
ficant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown database "MyProjectDB"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 988, in main
    cli.main()
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 579, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 427, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\cli.py", line 104, in migrate
    _migrate(directory, message, sql, head, splice, branch_label, version_path,
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\__init__.py", line 98, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\__init__.py", line 155, in migrate
    command.revision(config, message, autogenerate=True, sql=sql,
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 229, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 569, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\MyProjectDB\migrations\env.py", line 108, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\MyProjectDB\migrations\env.py", line 102, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 853, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 601, in run_migrations
    heads = self.get_current_heads()
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 533, in get_current_heads
    if not self._has_version_table():
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 549, in _has_version_table
    return sqla_compat._connectable_has_table(
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\sqla_compat.py", line 195, in _connectable_has_table
    return inspect(connectable).has_table(tablename, schemaname)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 283, in has_table
    return self.dialect.has_table(conn, table_name, schema)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\base.py", line 2018, in has_table
    info = self._get_table_pragma(
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\base.py", line 2545, in _get_table_pragma
    cursor = connection.exec_driver_sql(statement)
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1686, in exec_driver_sql
    return self._exec_driver_sql(
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1595, in _exec_driver_sql
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "H:\path\to\my\project\UserInterface\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Well, Flask-Migrate things your database is called `MyProjectDB`. Any idea why? Have you changed your alembic.ini file? Do you have an alternate configuration that uses sqlite3 with this database name? It seems your problem is that the wrong configuration is being applied.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have grep'd through the project tree and do not see any mentions of sqlite.  I found a "starter project" for `flask-security-too`.  I am ging to try that this morning with the thought that I amy be doing something out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was trying to follow Flask-Security-Too's "Basic SQLAlchemy Application with session" quick start guide.  I am not claiming it is incorrect but my understanding is probably flawed.

I decided to replace FST's "session" idea with the simpler "SQLAlchemy Application" sample and everything is rolling along just fine.

My best guess at the general issue is that maybe Alembic was not at the correct version or there are changes to the `env.py` file that I could not figure out.